# Firefox acrobat plugin inconsistant

Tags: firefox, pdf, adobe-acrobat

The firefox acrobat pdf plugin is displaying the PDF files in an inconsistent way.

[image]

Sometimes it's like the left, where there's only a few buttons floating at the bottom, and sometimes it's like the right where you have a full top bar with all function. I would like it to behave like the right all the time so I have full control. Is there a setting for that?

My current setting is this

[image]

Comment: Does the same PDF ever behave differently?

Comment: @Karan, I don't think so.

Comment: Then perhaps it's something to do with the PDFs themselves? Some might open up one way while others cause a different sort of UI to show up.

Comment: @Karan But Chrome never does this, it always opens PDFs in a consistent UI.

Comment: Does Chrome use the Acrobat PDF plugin as well, or its own internal viewer?

Comment: Chrome uses its own viewer. So you think the problem is Adobe not Firefox? It is the Adobe plug-in that opens PDFs in two different ways, not FF using two different plug-ins?

Comment: Yes, I'm guessing if you switch to using FF's new pdf.js internal viewer, you'll get a consistent UI in that browser too.